# Typescript class can't see methods (TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'method_name'))

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, compiler-errors, express-ws

While compiling there are no errors, compile fine. But when I call the method in the controller got an error. It looks like during the compilation class methods are missing.

If you need more information about the project config - please, ask - I will share. For now, I don't have any ideas on how to fix it. The similar code on other projects works fine.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onOpenMessage')
> at WebSocket. (/Users/xxx/redqueen-middleware/src/controllers/websocket.ts:23:16)
> at WebSocket.onMessage (/Users/xxx/redqueen-middleware/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16) at WebSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/Users/xxx/redqueen-middleware/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:1068:20)
> at Receiver.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at Receiver.dataMessage (/Users/xxx/redqueen-middleware/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:517:14)
> at Receiver.getData (/Users/xxx/redqueen-middleware/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:435:17)
> at Receiver.startLoop (/Users/xxx/redqueen-middleware/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:143:22)
> at Receiver._write (/Users/xxx/redqueen-middleware/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:78:10)
> at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:391:12)
> [ERROR] 16:46:06 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onOpenMessage')

Controller code

```
class WebsocketController {
  initWebsocket(websocket: WebSocket): void {
    //some code, works fine before calling method `onOpenMessage`
    this.onOpenMessage();
  }

  private onOpenMessage(): void {
    //some code
  }
}

export default new WebsocketController();
```

My `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./custom_typings",
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "config/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.test.ts",
    "custom_typings"
  ]
}
```

Here is my server.ts

```
import express from 'express';
import expressWs from 'express-ws';
import winston from 'winston';

import WebsocketController from './controllers/websocket';

export default function initServer() {
  const app = express();
  const port = process.env.PORT;
  const router = express.Router();
  global.websocketsList = [];

  expressWs(app);

  router.ws('/ws-request', WebsocketController.initWebsocket);

  app.use('/', router);

  app.listen(port, () => {
    winston.info(`Middleware server start on port ${port}`);
  });
}
```

Converting method `onOpenMessage` from private to public does not give any result.

Comment: Please show how you run `initWebsocket`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Thank you for your attention to my question. I've update first post with my server.ts information. I use this method as controller for websocket endpoint in my express.js server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are trying to use the instance method as statis
2. You lost `this` reference

Create an instance and use anonymous function instead:

```
const wsController = new WebsocketController() 
router.ws('/ws-request', () => wsController.initWebsocket());
```

Answer (score 0):

You never instantiate the class. Should

```
const wsController = new WebsocketController() 
router.ws('/ws-request', wsController.initWebsocket);
```

Or:

Export the instance from the controller file:

```
exports.default = new WebsocketController()
```

Comment: I use `export default new WebsocketController();` in controller code, but forgot add this to question. Sorry, edited.

Comment: Use this syntax then.
    router.ws('/ws-request', (ws, req) => wsController.initWebsocket()))
just don't forget to call the function and pass parameters manually if needed.